# How do I store sensor data in a specific time interval in .dat file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

This is the code I'm using to store sensor data in '**ecg.dat**'. Here, the data is stored from time=0 upto time=**interv**. What should I do if I want to store the data only in a specific interval say **200 to 300** in '**ecg.dat**'?

```
while(init_time<interv)
 c=readVoltage(b,'A0');
 x=[x,c] 
 subplot(211)
 plot(x);
 title('Recording live data....')
 fid = fopen('ecg.dat', 'w');
 fprintf(fid, '%d \n ', x);
 grid ON
 init_time=init_time+1;
 drawnow
 fclose(fid)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of your while loop

```
ind=200-init_time;  %assuming init time could be anything before 200
fid = fopen('ecg.dat','w');
y=x(ind:ind+100); %indexing 200 to three hundred.
fprintf(fid, '%d \n', y);
fclose(fid);
```

If init_time were always zero, then you could do `200:300`

You are also openning and closing the file `intrv` times.  You should `fopen` once before the loop and close when everything is done.